# dynamically adding a margin when div realigns due to change in page size using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a page in which I have a structure of divs in an inline block. Now each of the block divs have a minimum size and when the window size reduces to a size smaller than the sum of all the inner divs minimum width, I move some of the elements to the next line. I would now like a padding to be added to the div which moves to the next line alone and I am not looking to use js to achieve this. How can I do this in just CSS?

```
<div width="100%">
   <div style="display:inline-block; width=33%; max-width=300px; min-width=135px">
   <div style="display:inline-block; width=33%; max-width=300px; min-width=135px">
   <div style="display:inline-block; width=33%; max-width=300px; min-width=135px">
</div>
```

Rendering

---

```
    -------------------   -------------------  -------------------
   |                   | |                   ||                   |
   |                   | |                   ||                   |
   |     div1          | |     div 2         ||      div 3        |
   |                   | |                   ||                   |
    -------------------   -------------------  -------------------
```

---

constrained space

---

```
    -------------------   ------------------- 
   |                   | |                   |
   |                   | |                   |
   |     div1          | |     div 2         |
   |                   | |                   |
    -------------------   ------------------- 
    <^margin 5px inserted^>
    -------------------
   |                   | 
   |                   | 
   |       div 3       | 
   |                   | 
    -------------------
```

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use media queries to apply CSS rules based on the width of the viewport.

```
@media all and (max-width: _width_value_) {
    /* When the screen size is less than or equal to _width_value_ the css rules here will apply */
}
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mvJBk/) offering a solution to your original question.

Comment: I will accept answer tomorrow if this is the best way to do it, at the moment up-voting your answer..

Answer (score 1):

`margin-bottom` will do the trick, however, it'll be there even when all of the divs are on one line. There's no other way without the JavaScript imho:

```
.innderDiv {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 33%;
    max-width: 300px;
    min-width: 135px;
    border: 1px dashed;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ruslans/KNDFE/

Comment: Yes, I know of this, but this is not an effective solution for me at the moment. I need to take a lot of factors into account so I was hoping CSS might trigger this or with CSS3 there might be some way that this situation is taken into account.