# Horizontal slider each item taking 100% of window

Tags: html, css

I want to make a horizontal slider each item taking 100% of the window.
I do not want to specify the width of the container using CSS since they need to be dynamic.

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='item'>item1</div>
  <div class='item'>item2</div>
  <div class='item'>item3</div>
  <div class='item'>item4</div>
</div>
```

The CSS is as follows

```
.container{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.item{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

I want the items to be horizontally placed next to each other taking width of window into account and splitting the space equally; how can I do this ?

[EDIT]

[image: ROugh sketch]

Comment: It's already working how you want http://jsfiddle.net/kqvYJ/

Comment: So you want them to take 100% height? as you've added that in your code for some reason?

Comment: I don't get your requirement. Is this http://jsfiddle.net/kqvYJ/1/ what you are looking for or what @Morpheus mentioned?

Comment: I even want the items to be placed horizontally yo each other(side by side not below one another)

Comment: Check the fiddle I posted in my comment. If that works, I think you are looking for inline block. I suggest posting your questions more [diagrammatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15270729/dynamically-adding-a-margin-when-div-realigns-due-to-change-in-page-size-using-c)

Comment: I want somewhat this behaviour except that the item1,item2, item3,item4  are placed howizontally next to each other  http://jsfiddle.net/kqvYJ/1/

Comment: @VimalBasdeo have you seen my solution. can you respond to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display:table` for parent div and `display:table-cell` for child div like this

```
.container
{
    width:100%; 
    height:100%
    display:table;
}
.item
{
    width:100%;
    display:table-cell;
    padding:15px;
}
```

have a look here [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jfaws/)

Comment: This seems quite okay ,but still the width 100% of the item is not taking the window width

Comment: @VimalBasdeo ohh I missed that 100%. Have a look here http://jsfiddle.net/Jfaws/3/

Comment: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Jfaws/4/) also, try looking into CSS properties once you have the basic soln.

Comment: @Sachin The problem is the first div takes 100% and the rest take what space they have available. If Vimal needs exactly 100% of what each has he probably needs to look at css media queries.

Comment: thanks @Shouvik for your clarification.But only vimal can clarify what the actual requirement is.? :) I am  trying to work on your suggestion as well

Comment: Each item takes same width as the container that is the browser width

Comment: @VimalBasdeo If you want that each time should have same width then you can assign the widht:25% as like this http://jsfiddle.net/Jfaws/5/   sorry If I didn't understand your requirement then can u please show me a rough sketch of what you what, so that I can help you.

Comment: I have added a rough sketch of my requiremtnt

Comment: @VimalBasdeo so do you want three div inside the container having same width as browser window. in this case you will have horizontal scroller as well am i correct.?

Comment: yea that's exactly what i want

Comment: @VimalBasdeo Have a look here http://jsfiddle.net/Jfaws/7/. Here you have to assign the width of your container Nx times (number of items). Rest of things you can understand from fiddle. please respond if you any query.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Try with css and jquery. I hope that you get solutions.

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var totalWidth='';
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.container .item').each(function(index, element) {
        totalWidth = totalWidth+$(this).outerWidth(); 
    });
    $('.container_inner').width(totalWidth);
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.clear{display:block;height:0px;width:0px;clear:both;}
.container{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  overflow:auto;
}

.item{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  float:left;
}
</style>
<div class='container'>
    <div class="container_inner">
        <div class='item'>item1</div>
        <div class='item'>item2</div>
        <div class='item'>item3</div>
        <div class='item'>item4</div>
        <div class='clear'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems good but I would like looking for a slution using css first